# JSP redirect to different URL

Tags: java, jsp

In my application, user can subscribe to different clubs like for example Kid club, Youth club, Adult club and Elderly club. Now, suppose if user is already subscribed to Kid club on 7th October 2012 and if he again tries to subscribe the same club "Kid Club" on 2nd November 2012 then we try to redirect that user to another club such as Youth Club OR Adult Club OR Elderly Club. Each club has it's own domain such as (For example)

```
Kid club = kidclub.google.mobi
Youth Club = youthclub.yahoo.mobi
Adult Club=adult.godaddy.mobi
Elderly Club = elderly.google.mobi
```

Following is the sample code for redirection but this is not redirecting to different domain URL. Is it due to sendRedirect () method?Servlet is not used in this application. Only JSP is used with MySQL database in Apache Tomcat Server Please suggest asap.

```
 void doRedirect(HttpServletResponse response, String url)
    {
    try 
    {
    response.sendRedirect(url);
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
    e.printStackTrace()
    }
    }

    void redirectReturningUser( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
    response, ClubDomain currentDomain )
    {
    String redirectToUrl = currentDomain.getDefaultUrl();

    if( "kidclub.google.mobi".equals( currentDomain.getDefaultUrl() ) )
    redirectToUrl = "youthclub.yahoo.mobi";
    else if( "adult.godaddy.mobi".equals( currentDomain.getDefaultUrl() ) )
    redirectToUrl = "kidclub.google.mobi";
    else if( "youthclub.yahoo.mobi".equals( currentDomain.getDefaultUrl() ) )
    redirectToUrl = "adult.godaddy.mobi";
    else if( "adult.godaddy.mobi".equals( currentDomain.getDefaultUrl() ) )
    redirectToUrl = "elderly.google.mobi";
    else if( "elderly.google.mobi".equals( currentDomain.getDefaultUrl() ) )
    redirectToUrl = "adult.godaddy.mobi";

    doRedirect(response, "http://"+redirectToUrl );
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this the *entire* JSP? Or is there some more code into it which got executed as well because you're nowhere in the code returning after the redirect? Anyway, putting Java code incorrectly in a JSP file instead of a normal Java class (such as a servlet or filter) always leads to confusion among starters because JSP itself also participates in the HTTP response generation, while you actually want to perform the job *before* the HTTP response is generated. Just don't put Java code in a JSP file, there it is not for, it's to be used to generate HTML/CSS/JS code, not to control request/response.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that currentDomain.getDefaultUrl() is returning other url that the one you want. For example, it could be returning the url with http://?

Comment: @Christian Vielma..  Good point.. never thought of it. I will test it and get back to you soon if it doesn't happen.

Comment: @BaluC  This system is develped by some other programmers and I am mending it. Now as this is the urgent requirement I got to handle this in JSP page...So, any suggestion!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`response.sendRedirect(url);` works with relative (without `http:`) and absolute URLs, so the problem must be elsewhere.

The most common cause of problems is that some other code already started to write output to the response using `getOutputStream()` or `getWriter()`: As soon as the first byte is written that way, the HTTP header (which contains the redirect information) will be generated and send to the browser.

So you should look into `catalina.out` because the `e.printStackTrace()` was probably called.

You might also want to check what `currentDomain.getDefaultUrl()` returns; maybe the `if`s above simply never match.